# How to open new tab in Ubuntu Touch browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I just installed Ubuntu Touch on my OnePlus One. It still has limited capabilities on this device (no calling for example). But many things do work, and work quite nice and smooth actually.

I'm now writing this from the UTouch browser, and what puzzles me is how I can open a new tab. I can long press a link and then select "open in new tab", but I see no way of opening a new clean tab. On the right top I do see a little menu which only has the options:

- Share
- History
- Settings
- Private mode

Any idea how I could open a new tab? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at the bottom side of the screen there's a "(1)". Slide this up and you can find a "new tab".